# Popen and execl not giving the output of the user defined program

Tags: c, exec, popen

I'm trying to execute other programs within my C program.  My first attempt was with popen.  When I try to read from `pipe` I only get a reply of 1 byte and nothing in buf.  I'm not sure as to the reasoning behind this.

popen example:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
        FILE* pipe;
        if ((pipe=(FILE*)popen("./test.php","r"))==NULL)
                printf("this is not working\n");
        char buf[1024] = {'\0'};

        int fd=fileno(pipe);

        int bytes = read(fd, buf, 1024);

        printf("bytes read %d\n", bytes);

        printf("The program: %s\n", buf);
        if(pclose(pipe)<0)
                printf("not working\n");
        return 0;
}
```

php example

```
#!/usr/bin/php

<?php
echo "THIS IS A TEST THAT WORKED\n";
?>
```

The output:

```
bytes read 1
The program:
```

The output of ls:

```
ls -l test.php
-rwxr-xr-x+ 1 tpar44 user 62 Nov 10 14:42 test.php
```

Any help in this would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: still don't see any problem, could you add the output please ?

Comment: @mux neither do I, which is why I'm so perplexed at the moment

Comment: this might seem silly, but did you recompile the code :) ?

Comment: @mux haha yea i even got rid of the old executables from previous compilations just in case...I also copied and pasted the code from above into a new file just in case neither worked

Comment: @mux does it matter that the output from the php scrip is destined for stdout even though popen creates a pipe? is that output automatically redirected to the pipe? (I assumed this to be true but now im not so sure)

Comment: yes, the output is read through the pipe in the program and you print it, it should work, last thought, you should make sure you're in the same directory when executing the program, and the php script in the same directory

Comment: @mux yea I am, i moved everything into the same directory and change the path in oopen to `./test.php` because I thought that might have an issue...

Comment: maybe php is not installed ? or not in that path ? if it is then I really don't have clue :)

Comment: @mux I figured it out...It is working, there was no loop because I was just hacking the code together real quick.  That was a mistake because of the newline between the shebang and the php script was read and outputted.  So, when the while loop was put in, it received the php script output, ran the script, and then outputted the `echo` line.  Thanks for all you're help, I really appreciated it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to execute the php interpreter and pass the name of the script as argument, when using `popen` if your script does *not* have the shebang because the shell won't know which interpreter to use:

```
fp = popen("php /path/to/script/test.php", "r");
```

If the script has the shebang line you can just execute it, because `popen` uses the shell to execute commands and it can find out which one to use, so you could just do this:

```
 fp = popen("/path/to/script/test.php", "r");
```

However, make sure the script is executable:

```
chmod +x test.php
```

you could also use `execl()` but you have to specify the path to the binary because `execl` doesn't use the shell:

```
execl("/usr/bin/php", "/usr/bin/php", "-q",
      "/path/to/script/test.php", (char *) NULL);
```

Don't forget to actually read from the pipe ;)

```
fread(buf, 1, 1024, pipe);
```

Comment: ooh!! this is even true when the shebang is included as the first line?

Comment: @tpar44 this executes the script with the php interpreter which will ignore the first line, if you wish you could  execute it with bash instead, which will run the php.

Comment: I really appreciate the help but I'm still not seeing the output from the php script when the c program finishes executing...Am I not reading from the pipe correctly?

Comment: sorry I had taken it out when I posted, I fixed the popen example, but I know that the execl one doesn't explicitly read from the pipe but it dups stdin, stdout, and stderr so that it doesn't have to explicitly be read

Comment: @tpar44 just tested the popen example, and it works, like I said don't forget to make the script *executable*

Comment: @tpar44 no, what errors you got ? update the question, remove the `execl` if not needed